# Weird Ruby Enterprise Edition Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, ruby-enterprise-edition

I just installed Ruby Enterprise Edition and Passenger on an Ubuntu Hardy 8.04 VPS. As far as I'm aware, the installation was successful. My Rails application is accessible and on the whole, works fine. However, the part of my application where users can post comments using AJAX doesn't work. My `Comment` model has a setter method for the request as per [Railscasts episode 65](http://railscasts.com/episodes/65-stopping-spam-with-akismet):

```
def request=(request) 
  logger.info '*** Entered request setter method ***' # <- Never output!
  self.ip_address = request.remote_ip
  self.user_agent = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
  self.referrer   = request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
end
```

Everything works fine in development, but in production this method is never invoked and I get an HTTP 500 error when trying to post a comment. My production log is shown below.

I'm kind of at a loss as to how to debug this one, so would appreciate any pointers! I don't know what's trying to monkey-patch the `Fixnum` class with an `each` method.

**EDIT:** It turns out that there's [a known issue with the Hoptoad exception notifier](http://help.hoptoadapp.com/discussions/problems/257-rake-hoptoadtest-fails-with-undefined-method-each-for-0fixnum) that explains the `Fixnum` issue. It still doesn't explain why my request setter isn't called by REE though!

---

production.log

Aug 08 17:06:14 railsapp rails[4666]: "\nNoMethodError (undefined method `each' for 1:Fixnum):\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:91:in`process_request'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:206:in `main_loop'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:376:in`start_request_handler'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:334:in `handle_spawn_application'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:182:in`safe_fork'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:332:in `handle_spawn_application'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in`**send**'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in `main_loop'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:195:in`start_synchronously'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:162:in `start'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:213:in`start'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:261:in `spawn_rails_application'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in`lookup_or_add'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:255:in `spawn_rails_application'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in`synchronize'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:254:in`spawn_rails_application'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:153:in `spawn_application'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:286:in`handle_spawn_application'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in `__send__'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in`main_loop'\n  passenger (2.2.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:195:in `start_synchronously'\n\n"
Aug 08 17:06:14 railsapp rails[4666]: "/!\\ FAILSAFE /!\\  Sat Aug 08 17:06:14 +0000 2009\n  Status: 500 Internal Server Error\n  undefined method`each' for 1:Fixnum\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:489:in `filter_parameters'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:496:in`filter_parameters'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:495:in `collect'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:495:in`filter_parameters'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:489:in `each'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:489:in`filter_parameters'\n    /home/deploy/public_html/railsapp/releases/20090808155352/vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/lib/hoptoad_notifier.rb:309:in `clean_notice'\n    /home/deploy/public_html/railsapp/releases/20090808155352/vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/lib/hoptoad_notifier.rb:235:in`notify_hoptoad'\n    /home/deploy/public_html/railsapp/releases/20090808155352/vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/lib/hoptoad_notifier.rb:226:in `rescue_action_in_public'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:154:in`rescue_action_without_handler'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:74:in `rescue_action'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:527:in`send'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:527:in `process_without_filters'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in`process'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:65:in `call_with_exception'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:91:in`dispatch'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:111:in `_call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:82:in`initialize'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in`call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in`call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:122:in `call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in`call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in`cache'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in`call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/vendor/rack-1.0.0-git/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:91:in`process_request'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:206:in `main_loop'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:376:in`start_request_handler'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:334:in `handle_spawn_application'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:182:in`safe_fork'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:332:in `handle_spawn_application'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in`**send**'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in `main_loop'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:195:in`start_synchronously'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:162:in `start'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:213:in`start'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:261:in `spawn_rails_application'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in`lookup_or_add'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:255:in `spawn_rails_application'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in`synchronize'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:254:in`spawn_rails_application'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:153:in `spawn_application'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:286:in`handle_spawn_application'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in `__send__'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:351:in`main_loop'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:195:in `start_synchronously'\n    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.4/bin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Hoptoad and try it again.  From what I can tell in that textwall of a stack trace your controller isn't being called.  It's blowing up trying to parse the incoming params.